# Should an image's max-width property be applied before or after the size of its containing table cell is computed?

Tags: css

Consider the following code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kyuep4e/)):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img 
                src=some-image.png
                style="max-width: 100%;"
            >
        </td>
        <td style="
            width: 100%; 
            background: yellow;
        ">
            the second cell
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Firefox 33 and Internet Explorer 11 render this one way, while Chrome 38 renders it differently.  In FF/IE, the image is displayed at its natural size.  In Chrome, the image completely disappears (having been shrunk into oblivion).

It appears to me that the browsers disagree on the meaning of `max-width` when provided in the context of an auto-sized table cell, where the cell is part of a table whose width exceeds the window.  I would have expected the image cell's width to be computed *before* application of `max-width' property.

I realize this is a totally contrived example.  I'm not looking for work-arounds; I'm asking because I'm simply interested in learning about the corner cases of CSS rules.

CSS defines some pretty specific rules about box sizing and layout computation order when it comes to percentages.  Any ideas what's going on here?  Which browser is right?

Comment: Regarding `max-width` with a percentage value: ["If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1."](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-max-width) #chromedefended

Comment: Great point.  From this, perhaps we can conclude that in this matter, no browser is right and no browser is wrong.  Historically, the subjective and opinionated rendering of incorrect HTML and CSS has been a source of fuel for browser wars.  Remember the cop-out tagline, "This site looks best on ___?"  Still, when code is wrong -- and most of the HTML/CSS out there *is* wrong, to some degree -- the least surprising result is the most desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing this as an answer:

[From the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-max-width), regarding max-width with a percentage value:

> If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then
>   the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.